# AppleScript : get the current fiscal quarter for Ireland

Tags: date, applescript, fiscal

I need to get the current quarter for Ireland set as a variable for an AppleScript.
I have no clue how to procede to get this quarter generated.

Any idea?

cheers

```
-- January / February / March = 1Q
-- April / May / June = 2Q
-- July / August / September = 3Q
-- October / November / December = 4Q
```

Comment: You could run a shell command like `TZ='Europe/Dublin' date +'%m'` which will give you the month number and then modulus 3 divide and add 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean

```
set currentMonth to month of (current date) as integer
set currentQuarter to (((currentMonth - 1) div 3 + 1) as text) & "Q"
```

Edit: Or the AppleScriptObjC version including setting the time zone

```
use framework "Foundation"

set currentCalendar to current application's NSCalendar's currentCalendar()
set dublinTimeZone to current application's NSTimeZone's timeZoneWithName:"Europe/Dublin"
set currentCalendar's timeZone to dublinTimeZone
set currentMonth to (currentCalendar's component:(current application's NSCalendarUnitMonth) fromDate:(current application's NSDate's |date|)) as integer
set currentQuarter to (((currentMonth - 1) div 3 + 1) as text) & "Q"
```

Comment: How does this set the timezone to Ireland please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I added an ASOC version setting the time zone

Comment: Nice! Thank you for taking the time to answer.